# ScrollView RelativeLayout element at the bottom is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` within `ScrollView` with different elements inflated inside a `Fragment`.

What I have observed is the element at the bottom of the `RelativeLayout` is not visible.
 The `scroll` is enabled as I scroll down but the bottom-most element is never visible.

I have tried below as well,still the same

1) Using `LinearLayout`

2) Using a different element at the bottom.

The layout file content is as below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp" >

  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/center_divider1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCountry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_divider1"
    android:entries="@array/category" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinnerCountry"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerCountry"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:entries="@array/cars_vehicles" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/center_divider2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerCity"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/condition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_divider2">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioUsed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Used"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New" />

  </RadioGroup>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/center_divider3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/condition"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_list_price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_divider3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="price" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_list_year"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_price">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="year of purchase" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_list_kms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_year" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="kms" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_list_mileage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_kms" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mileage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="mileage" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <RadioGroup
      android:id="@+id/airCondition"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_mileage" >

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/Yes"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Yes"
          android:checked="true" />

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/No"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="No" />
  </RadioGroup>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_list_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/airCondition" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="description"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:maxLines="5" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_list_description"
    android:text="Submit.." />

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: how about if the scollview is set to height = match_parent

Answer (score 1):

I copied your layout into a test app and it looks good to me. I assume that the view you cannot see is the Submit... button, right?

[image]

Are you running this on an actual phone or on an emulator?

Maybe try adding a bottom margin to that button (just for testing) to see if somehow that will make it visible.

Comment: Thanks it works after adding the bottom margin. It's strange though, not sure what could be the reason? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a sample app and was able to see the bottom element. Attached screenshots of the start and end of the scroll. I believe the bottom element is the button. Are you still having the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am trying to set this on the actual phone. What could be the reason? The element at the bottom is the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding this to my grid layout

android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

Comment: increase or decrease dp value as needed